# MySQL Select and IF() Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I'm kind of new to MySQL and I need help. I have a table `Invoices` and a table `Payments`. I am having trouble generating a report that will show all invoices that were paid in `In Full` or a `Partial Payment` was received by 12/31/2019.  One Invoice can be paid by one or more payments (For example a partial payment, such as 25% down, and the remainder payment on completion of work). How can I create SQL query that will select ALL records from `Invoices` and then for each Invoice select matching Payment, compare it to the `Invoice Total` and will display either `Paid in Full` or `partial Payment`? I have the following code:

```
SELECT Invoices.InvoiceID, Invoices.ClientName, Invoices.InvoiceTotal
INNER JOIN InvoiceStatus ON InvoiceStatus.InvoiceStatusID = Invoices.InvoiceStatus
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
AND (Invoices.InvoiceStatus = '1' OR Invoices.InvoiceStatus = '2')
 AND (Invoices.InvoiceActive != 0 OR Invoices.InvoiceActive IS NULL)
ORDER BY ClientName

SELECT Payment.PaymentID, Payment.PaymentReceivedAmount, Payment.PaymentReceivedDate FROM `Payment` 
INNER JOIN Invoices ON Invoices.InvoiceID = Payment.InvoiceID
WHERE PaymentReceivedDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
```

If I do `INNER JOIN` then I get two rows for an Invoice that was paid with two payment. I know that I also need to implement IF() statement to show `Paid in Full` and `Partial Payment` but I'm a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your queries miss FROM, definitely will not run. Also description not really matches code, please improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both tables, aggregate by invoice, and use `sum()` to compute the total payment. Finally, a `case` expression can be used to display the status:

```
select i.invoiceid, i.clientname, i.invoicetotal, 
    coalesce(sum(p.PaymentReceivedAmount), 0) as paymenttotal,
    case when i.invoicetotal <=> sum(p.PaymentReceivedAmount) then 'In Full' else 'Partial Payment' end as paymentstatus
from invoices i
left join payment p 
    on  p.invoiceid = i.invoiceid
    and p.paymentreceiveddate >= '2019-01-01' and p.paymentreceiveddate < '2020-01-01'
where 
    i.invoicedate >= '2019-01-01' and i.invoicedate < '2020-01-01'
    and i.invoicestatus in (1, 2)
    and (i.invoiceactive <> 0 or i.invoiceactive is null)
group by i.invoiceid
order by clientname
```

Notes:

- The `left join` allows invoices without any payment in the period.
- I used the same date filters as in your original queries, but optimized it a little by turning it to half-open intervals.
- It does not seem like you need table `invoicestatus` to achieve the result you want.