# MySQL - SELECT ALL LEFT JOIN INCLUDING NULL

Tags: mysql, select

I am having trouble with the following.

I have a table `Invoices` and a table `Payment`s that list all payments received.

One Invoice can be paid by one or more payments (For example a partial payment, such as 25% down, and the remainder payment on completion of work).

I need to create a report that will select all invoices from `Invoices` and sums up all payments from `Payments`.

I also need to be able to select all invoices that have not any payment received.

I have the following code but it selects only invoices with an existing payment(s) in `Payments`.

How can I include ALL invoices in the statement even the ones that have no payment received?

I assume I need to include `NULL` in the statement but I am not sure how to do it.

```
SELECT p.ClientName
     , p.InvoiceID
     , p.InvoiceTotalWithTax SUM(c.PaymentReceivedAmount)
  FROM `Invoices`  p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Payment c
    ON p.InvoiceID = c.InvoiceID
   AND p.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
 WHERE c.PaymentReceivedDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
 GROUP 
    BY p.InvoiceID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't get it: why did you modify the query I provided to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097737/mysql-select-and-if-statement), that addresses this problem already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include conditions like `c.PaymentReceivedDate BETWEEN '2019-1-1  00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'` in your WHERE clause, they will only be true if c.PaymentReceivedDate is not null, which will only be true if there was a Payment row found.  Essentially, it turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.  If you want to restrict which Payment rows can be joined, that needs to be in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN, not in the WHERE clause, in order to still select rows where there is no record to join.